# Qt. Undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Имеются следующие файлы:

SortedSequence.h:

```
#ifndef SORTEDSEQUENCE_H
#define SORTEDSEQUENCE_H

#include "seqiterator.h"

template<class T>
class SortedSequence
{
protected:
    int length;
public:
    SortedSequence();
    virtual ~SortedSequence();
    bool empty();
    virtual SeqIterator<T> begin() = 0;
    virtual SeqIterator<T> end() = 0;
    virtual void add(const T & element, int (*comparator)(const T&, const T&)) = 0;
    virtual void add(const T & element) = 0;
};

#endif // SORTEDSEQUENCE_H
```

---

SortedSequence.h:

```
#include "SortedSequence.h"

template<class T>
SortedSequence<T>::SortedSequence() : length(0) {}

template<class T>
SortedSequence<T>::~SortedSequence() {}

template<class T>
bool SortedSequence<T>::empty() { return this->length == 0; }
```

---

ASortedSequence.h:

```
#ifndef ASORTEDSEQUENCE_H
#define ASORTEDSEQUENCE_H

#include "SortedSequence.h"

template<class T>
class ASortedSequence : public SortedSequence<T>
{
    T * array;
public:
    explicit ASortedSequence();
    ~ASortedSequence();
    SeqIterator<T> begin();
    SeqIterator<T> end();
    void add(const T & element, int (*comparator)(const T&, const T&));
    void add(const T & element);
};

#endif // ASORTEDSEQUENCE_H
```

---

ASortedSequence.cpp:

```
#include "ASortedSequence.h"

template<class T>
ASortedSequence<T>::ASortedSequence()
{
    this->array = nullptr;
    this->length = 0;
}

template<class T>
ASortedSequence<T>::~ASortedSequence()
{
    if (this->length == 0) return;
    else delete[] array;
}

template<class T>
void ASortedSequence<T>::add(const T & element, int (*comparator)(const T &, const T &))
{
    // ...
}

template<class T>
void ASortedSequence<T>::add(const T & element)
{
    // ...
}

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T> ASortedSequence<T>::begin() { return SeqIterator<T>(array); }

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T> ASortedSequence<T>::end() { return SeqIterator<T>(0); }
```

---

seqiterator.h:

```
#ifndef SEQITERATOR_H
#define SEQITERATOR_H

#include <iterator>

template<class T>
class SeqIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{
    T * currentPlace;
public:
    SeqIterator(T * ptr);
    SeqIterator(const SeqIterator<T> & iter);
    SeqIterator<T> & operator++ ();
    SeqIterator<T> operator++ (int);
    bool operator== (const SeqIterator<T> & r);
    bool operator!= (const SeqIterator<T> & r);
    T & operator* ();
};

#endif // SEQITERATOR_H
```

---

seqiterator.cpp:

```
#include "seqiterator.h"

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T>::SeqIterator(T * ptr) : currentPlace(ptr) {}

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T>::SeqIterator(const SeqIterator<T> & iter) : currentPlace(iter.currentPlace) {}

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T> & SeqIterator<T>::operator++ () { ++currentPlace; return *this; }

template<class T>
SeqIterator<T> SeqIterator<T>::operator++ (int) { SeqIterator<T> tmp (*this); operator ++(); return tmp; }

template<class T>
bool SeqIterator<T>::operator== (const SeqIterator<T> & r) { return currentPlace == r.currentPlace; }

template<class T>
bool SeqIterator<T>::operator!= (const SeqIterator<T> & r) { return currentPlace != r.currentPlace; }

template<class T>
T & SeqIterator<T>::operator* () { return *currentPlace; }
```

---

.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Search
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
widget.cpp \
SortedSequence.cpp \
ASortedSequence.cpp \
seqiterator.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
SortedSequence.h \
ASortedSequence.h \
seqiterator.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

---

А теперь сам вопрос:
Следующий код:

```
ASortedSequence<int> seq;
// …
for (…)
    seq.add(number.toInt());
// …
for (auto iter = seq.begin(); iter != seq.end(); ++iter)
    ui->output->append(QString(*iter));
```

Вызывает следующие ошибки:

[image: Ошибки]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не доглядел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не помещайте определения шаблонных функций/классов в отдельные .cpp-файлы. Размещайте все только в заголовочных файлах - иначе инстанцирования не происходит, вот и имеем, что имеем.

Совет от Страуструпа (A Tour of C++, adv. 7-6):

> Раздельной компиляции шаблонов нет: вы должны включать с помощью директивы #include определения шаблонов в каждую единицу трансляции, которая их использует.